# Return total number of rows from mulitple .csv

Tags: r, csv

I hope someone can help, and that I haven't missed something important in my searches for answers (I am very new to R):
I am trying to import multiple .csv files and then return the number of rows in each with the original file name as an output. The csv files are named 50001.15, 50002.15, etc

So far I have (importing all the .csv from the dir)

```
files=list.files(pattern="*.csv")

for(file in files)

{

perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")

assign(

gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 

read.csv(paste("C:/Users/NAMEetc/",file,sep="")))

}
```

And I can conduct nrow
`nrow(50001.15)` 
to return my result for an individual file, but I was hoping to do it for all in one process

I have had a play around with a load of other bits in an attempt (will just cause too much confusion if I enter it here). Is there a way to string nrow returns together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `files <- list.files(pattern='.*\\.csv', full.names=TRUE); library(data.table); lst <- lapply(files, fread); v1 <- sapply(lst, nrow); names(v1) <- sub('\\.csv', '', basename(files))`

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the `files` into a `list` with `fread` from `data.table`, get the `nrow` in a `vector`, change the `names` of elements in the `vector` by extracting the file names from 'files' using `sub`

```
 files <- list.files(pattern='.*\\.csv', full.names=TRUE)
 library(data.table)
 lst <- lapply(files, fread)
 v1 <- sapply(lst, nrow)
 names(v1) <- sub('\\.csv', '', basename(files))
```